# Starting nodejs asynchronous from Jenkins

Tags: node.js, jenkins, blocking

I am currently implementing some mock http host using a node.js server. This server should be started by a jenkins CI job. After its started integration tests from JMeter should be performed and afterwards the node.js server should be shut down.

Right now i am having the problem that i can without problem start the node.js server as well as the jmeter test file alone. The problem is, that the node.js execution blocks the Jenkins Job and therefore the JMeter tests which are launched after Node are never actually started. Therefore i was wondering if there is a way to start a node.js server in the background, let it listen until the JMeter tests are over then shut it down again.

I guess the shutdown can be achieved using some special request to the nodejs server, but the main problem is that starting the nodejs http server blocks the entire jenkins process and thus the JMeter tests never start.

Is there a way to tell Jenkins that it should start the nodejs server but should not wait for it to end? Thanks in advance, Cromon

Comment: Since our jenkins is running on a unix server i guess starting it as `nodejs app.js &` should do the trick?

Comment: start it as `node app.js`

Comment: Facing something similar, either grunt task or using Express, the process hangs. If you use &, then, how to kill the process in the next build?

Comment: I ended up using a postbuild step that sends a signal to the asynchronously running nodejs server to shut down.

Comment: @Cromon can you please elaborate on how you did it? thanks

Comment: I am also facing the same issue, node server starts, but then no other jobs are getting executed which are queued. What can be done, I am really stuck. I have tried using 'nodejs app.js &' but again same thing is happening , server keeps on listening on the specified port, thats it.